# SSRS report takes 75-90 seconds to render

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]I've a SSRS report that takes between 75 - 90 seconds to render. Can someone suggest to way to speed up the report? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: How fast does the query run outside of the report?  You likely need to tune your query.

Comment: Please run this query: http://pastebin.com/aVfpFDha , take a screenshot of the results, and post the screenshot.

Comment: @kheld - It takes 15 sec to run the query.

Comment: @Michael - I tried running the query you suggested. I get an error message 'Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.'. any suggestions

Comment: Looks like you had some that have a zero second rendering time. Get rid of the last [RowsPerSecond] column (just comment it out or delete). That should resolve the error.

Comment: @Michael - I ran the query you suggested for a specific report (Invoices by Customer) which takes a long time render. I've added the screenshot to my question above.

Comment: Have you looked at report server caching?

Comment: @AndyDufresne - I have not looked at report server caching. Can you please share your thoughts on caching. The report that takes a long time to render is invoice report which needs to update every time a new invoice is created. Will caching the report show all the records?

Comment: Have a look at these - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522786.aspx & http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2010/02/11/caching-ssrs-reports-for-performance.aspx